# How to make an object only cast a shadow but be invisible in a View Layer?

Tags: shadows, render-passes, viewlayers

This may be something very simple but I actually tried a bunch of things without any success.

I am looking or a setup that allows me to do this in 2.8+.

Let's say I have a cube sitting on a plane and I want to have two render passes the first one with the cube and the second one with the plane and the cube's shadow:

**Scene**

[image]

**Pass 01, foreground**

[image]

**Pass 02, background + shadows**

[image]

The setup was very simple in 2.7-, I just put the plane in the second layer and have 2 Render Layers `foreground` and `background` respectively. If I put the lamp on both layers, I get the result I want.

In 2.8+, however, we now have Collections and View Layers and I tried a lot of setups but none of them allowed me to have an equivalent of this. For instance, I tried puting the objects on two different View Layers but it doesn't allow the cube cast a shadow on the plane unless I use `Holdout` wich just leaves a big hole in the place of the cube on the background pass. I also tried using `Indirect only` but that renders the cube on the background pass.

Can anyone here suggest me a setup that can make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simple... In Cycles.

## Cycles

First, you need to have 2 view layers, so I guess You have no problems with it:

[image]

Next, enable *Indirect only* toggle:

[image]

Then, enable this for one collection with cube:

[image]
*Lamp in the wrong collection in my screenshot, sorry for that*

In other view layer, disable second collection:

[image]

This is an analog of exclude in 2.7x, but you can also use *Indirect only* of course, to have reflections from plane:

[image]

So this is it, as you see it is just the same as in 2.7x, but the buttons in the different places.

But it works only in Cycles, EEVEE doesn't support  *Indirect only*. For EEVEE I can suggest a workaround.

## EEVEE

Duplicate collection with cube and make transparent material for the cube. Set alpha mode to *Alpha Clip* or *Blend*, but set shadows to *Opaque*:

[image]

Then disable collection with solid cube for layer one:

[image]

And enable original cube for layer 2:

[image]

This will work, but not expect screen space reflections to work (Cube will not reflect plane) But baked reflections and irradiance volume will work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I probably missed a step when I tried to use `Indirect Only`.